# JSON data not appearing in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to incorporate this JSON code into my webpage:

```
function getimage(input) {

    $.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?callback=?", {
        q: input,
        v: '1.0'
    }, function (data) {
        $("#r").html("Picture: ");
        $("#r").append('<img src="' + data.responseData.results[0].url + '">');

    });
}
```

There is a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1357/

This example works exactly as I want it to, but on my webpage, no image appears when I click the button.

I have had a look at Chrome developer tools and the error I get it

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

For some reason the data result I am getting back doesn't get through and I have no clue why - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle has console errors also and isn't displaying an image

Comment: are you sure? It works for me - I just typed 'paris' into the textbox, clicked 'execute' and it displayed an image below the box...

Comment: Maybe it's because I didn't type anything.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should've made it clear - when I've got this working the user will (hopefully) be able to do a google search for an image which will be used as a background for a div